# Chrome Extension: How to detect if an extension is installed using Content Scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, inject, content-script

I am asking this question after looking at several related questions on stackoverflow. I started with [how to detect if an extension is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293601/206613). I opted for the method where I add a div to body using content scripts on some pages. Here is how I did it...

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Install Check",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://host.com/*"],
            "js" : ["insert_node.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "host.com/*"
    ]
}
```

insert_node.js (content script)

```
var insert_node = document.createElement('div');
insert_node.id = "HOST_SITE";
document.body.appendChild(insert_node);
```

host page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a host site. Welcome!!!</h1>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="notification.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

extension install script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#HOST_SITE').length > 0) {
        alert("you have our extension installed");
    } else {
        alert("not installed");
    }
});
```

My problem is that the alert with message `not_installed` always pops up before the chrome can inject the node in DOM. I read about `run_at` attribute in [manifest.json over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124054/206613). But that didn't solve the problem either. I tried all the three `document_start`, `document_idle`, `document_end` values. What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: When is the 'extension install script' executed? Did you check whether the insertion actually takes place and the div is inserted?

Comment: Yes the insertion is taking place. I double checked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your own the extension and website, in which case it would be much easier to use [Inline Installation](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html).

```
if (typeof chrome !== "undefined" && typeof chrome.app !== "undefined" && chrome.app.isInstalled) {
  // extension is installed.
}
```

Comment: Much better suggestion than mine, Id definitely go with this.

Comment: @abraham - So this script works in any site? I mean I don't have to include the site domain somewhere? somewhere in like permissions or allowed URLs or something?

Comment: @ShiVik: Read the **verified site requirement** section from the link.

Comment: @abraham I am having problem with chrome.app.isInstalled. After the installation, it won't return true until I refresh my page or open another page through the extension. Is that the same case for you? Thx.

Comment: as far as I understand chrome.app.isInstalled refers to apps and NOT to extensions (my tests confirm this)

Comment: Might want to include an additional check to make sure other browsers don't throw an error: if (typeof chrome !== "undefined" && chrome.app.isInstalled) { ... }

Comment: what extension did you check on this method?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how to do this with JQuery as `$("#something")` only seems to search the head and body?...and we need `document.documentElement`.  Reason being that we are inserting something at document_start and there's no body/head then, but there is documentElement.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Install Check",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["HOST"],
            "js" : ["myscript.js"],
            "run_at":"document_start"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "HOST"
    ],
    "version":"1.0"
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
var insert_node = document.createElement('div');
insert_node.id = "HOST_SITE";
document.documentElement.appendChild(insert_node);
```

**notification.js**

```
if (document.documentElement.querySelector("#HOST_SITE")) {
    alert("Installed");
} else {
    alert("Not Installed");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working...

- Make the extension insert content script after DOM loads but before other resources like images are loaded

manifest.json (added `"run_at": "document_end"`)

```
{
    "name": "Install Check",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://host.com/*"],
            "js" : ["insert_node.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "host.com/*"
    ]
}
```

- use `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready`

insert_node.js (changed the `$(document).ready` to `window.onload`)

```
window.onload = function() {
    if ($('#HOST_SITE').length > 0) {
        alert("you have our extension installed");
    } else {
        alert("not installed");
    }
};
```

However, I don't completely understand why using `window.onload` works and `$(document).ready` does not.

May be someone can shed some light on that?

**Also I agree with @abraham that using `chrome.app.isInstalled` is a better way to do this (answer to my comment would be the icing on cake) :)**