# Chrome Manifest.json syntax error

Tags: json, google-chrome-app

I am working on a chrome app and its basically done, however I am adding code to my customer's website to have it determine if the app is installed on chrome or not.

In order to do this I need to check for a file "manifest.json" is available for the app to determine if its installed or not.

I am using the below code that I got from another posted question on here:

```
function detectChromeExtension(extensionId, accesibleResource, callback){
            if (typeof(chrome) !== 'undefined'){
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    testUrl = 'chrome-extension://' +extensionId +'/' +accesibleResource;
                    xmlHttp.open('HEAD', testUrl, true);
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xmlHttp.timeout = 1000;

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && typeof(callback) == 'function') {
                    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                        callback.call(this, true);
                    } else {
                        callback.call(this, false);
                    }
                }
            }        
            xmlHttp.ontimeout = function() {
                if (typeof(callback) == 'function')
                    callback.call(this, false);
                }        
                xmlHttp.send();
            } else {
                if (typeof(callback) == 'function')
                    callback.call(this, false);
            }    
        };

        detectChromeExtension('gcjbmhbihobfgpjmfbooldocijijdpig', 'manifest.json', myCallbackFunction);

        function myCallbackFunction(extensionExists) {
            if (extensionExists){
                console.log('Extension present');
            } else {
                console.log('Extension not present');
            }
        }
```

By checking the chrome console I am getting the following output:

Denying load of chrome-extension://gcjbmhbihobfgpjmfbooldocijijdpig/manifest.json. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

so to fix this I am trying to add "web_accessible_resources": ["manifest.json"] into my manifest.json but it tells me that this line doesn't follow syntax.

Here is the full manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Watch TBR",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"default_locale": "en",
"description": "Easy access to WatchTBR.com",
"icons": { "128": "icon_128.png", "16": "icon_16.png" },
"app": {
"urls": [
  "http://www.watchtbr.com/"
],
"launch": {
  "web_url": "http://www.watchtbr.com/"
}
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["manifest.json"],
"permissions":["http://www.watchtbr.com"]
}
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike extensions, there is no way for a website to access packaged app's resources. If you own both the site and the app, you can use the [inline installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) feature of Chrome WebStore and test if the app is installed with `chrome.app.isInstalled`.

At the moment, the `isInstalled` method is limited to hosted apps, but [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227178) tracks the packaged apps support.

If you don't own the app or just want to share a link to the app (if installed) or to the store entry (if not installed), there is a feature request you can star and track progress at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161054

Comment: Then how does Crackle.com detect that I do not have their app installed and ask me to install it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9314807/344467 You can see this by looking at that site's JS source code.

Comment: that's the problem Crackle's source is gibberish I can't find the JS code they are using to pull up that popup window. Ill try that link you posted

Comment: Updated the answer with Inline installation as per @sowbug's comment.