# Manipulating original HTML DOM from server with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension where I have to manipulate the original HTML DOM sent from server and not the generated DOM. How to make my content_scripts run before other javascript files received from server are run. I didnt find anything useful till now.

Here is my manifest

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "DOMMAN",
"description": "DOM manip",
"version": "0.1",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/"
],
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js":["jquery.min.js","back_call.js"],
    "matches":["http://*/*","https://*/*"]
}],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
}
```

I want the content_scripts to run before anything else. How to do that?

Comment: Check the "run_at" attribute in content_script/manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `manifest.json`:

```
{
  // other stuff
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  // other stuff
}
```

(From [how can i use a chrome extension content script to inject html into a page at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536035/how-can-i-use-a-chrome-extension-content-script-to-inject-html-into-a-page-at-st))

Your code would look like this:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js":["jquery.min.js","back_call.js"],
    "matches":["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```